# jquery ui autocomplete custom display prevent item selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have altered the options display like this

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    ......
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    //customizeaza selection list-ul 
    return $("<li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<input type='text' maxlength='3' size='3' /><a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.den_prod + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul)
};
```

so now I have a text input field for each option returned by autocomplete, but when I am trying to click in the field to type some value the corresponding option is selected and the popup closed. How can i prevent that ?

Comment: So you want to prevent closing menu after selection?

Comment: no, i want to type some value in the input field (see the .append("<input type='text' />") ), but now when I am trying to do that the option from that line is selected and my options list closed so i ca't type in the generated field.

Comment: So when should the menu close? After pressing enter in that input maybe?

Comment: on anchor (a tag) press( you can see that the input it is not nested into the anchor) or escape key